# Computing a Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K=\mathbb Q$ and $L$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $f(x)=x^4-6x^2+4$. I want to calculate the Galois group $\text{Gal}(L/K)$.

The zeros of $f$ are obviously

$x_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}$ and $x_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}$

Hence we have $L=\mathbb Q(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$

I have the suspicion that the extension is generated by just one of them, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\left(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}\right) \left(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}\right)=?$

Comment: $(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}})(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}})=\sqrt{9-5}=2$, hence the exntension is generated just by $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}$?

Comment: @Mathlearner: Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You already know the extension's Galois Group is of order four, and there aren't that many groups of that order.

You may also want to use that in fact

$$L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,,\,\sqrt3)\;$$

From the above, you must be able to deduce your group isn't cyclic.

Comment: How can I see that the polynomial is irreducible in order the show that $[L:K]=4$?

Comment: (1) It has no rational roots (easy), (2) It has no quadratic factors (less easy): assume $\;(x^2+ax+b)\mid (x^4-6x^2+4)\;$ in $\;\Bbb Q[x]\;$ . You will end with two equations without solutions in the rationals, something like $$\begin{cases}&I\;\;\;a(a^2-2b-6)=0\\{}\\&II\;\;\;b(b-a^2+6)=0\end{cases}$$